# How to use json in d3.js Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I am using the gem gon to create json from my Rails database.

I am able to do this successfully and show the results in an alert although I would like to show it in d3.js

I have a database called users (name:string,value:integer)
I would like to pass just the values to json so these can be graphed.

Is it better to try to do this in the controller or to pass the whole table into json and then configure d3 to graph the parts I want?

Trying the former as follows

```
 class GraphController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end

    def data
     gon.users = @users.value.as_json
    @users = User.value
    end   
 end
```

gives me the error:

```
 NoMethodError in GraphController#data
  undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

and this highlights the line

```
   gon.users = @users.value.as_json
```

Im not quite sure how to graph the values I want

## UPDATE

So on recommendation I have now ditched gon and reverted back to creating json the old fashioned way and then trying to call it from an ajax call.
The controller therefore looks like this:

```
    def data
    render :json =>  User.select('value')
  end
end
```

and I make exactly the same call to data using the ajax as set out in the tutorial I am trying to follow [here](http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302)

However this doesnt show me the bar graph I want and return a hash of id and value in json format.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually loading any users from the database:

```
 class GraphController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end

   def data
     @users = User.all
     gon.users = @users.value.as_json
     @users = User.value
   end   
end
```

> Is it better to try to do this in the controller or to pass the whole
>   table into json and then configure d3 to graph the parts I want?

This is a matter of opinion but I would say that it's better to create a well thought out API which exposes your resources as JSON in a way that fits many uses.

I would also ditch `gon` and use plain old JSON and Ajax. Injecting data into javascript from the server via script tags is kind of an anti-pattern. It relies on globals, creates timing issues and makes your controllers coupled to the behavior of javascripts components on the page.

Applications which take the "eat your own dogfood" approach and consume their own API's tend to be better executed and far more modular.

Comment: OK so assuming I ditch gon then to get my controller to give me the value column from the user table would I just reference url: 'graph/data', in ajax to get the data from my graph controller? And would I use the code you have supplied above to define the json? Bit confused......

Comment: Yes something like that. You need to setup your controller to respond to JSON as well. Google for `rails JSON api`. There are plenty of tutorials detailing how to accomplish this.